# trying to find if a string contains a string

Tags: php, string

I am trying to find whether or not a string is contained within a string, but it is always true. Why is this always true

```
<?php

$test = 'ORDER BY `views`';
if(strpos($test,'views') !== true) echo 'true';
else echo 'false';

?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the parameters for `strpos()` incorrectly.

You're using `strpos($needle, $haystack)` but it should actually be `strpos($haystack, $needle)`

Note that `strpos()` returns `FALSE` if the needle was not found in the haystack. So, you'll need to check if it returns `FALSE` (instead of `TRUE`).

With your code, it becomes:

```
if(strpos($test, 'views') !== FALSE) 
    echo 'true';
else 
    echo 'false';
```

[**Demo!**](https://eval.in/53185)

Comment: Sorry, that was an accident just from experimenting, but I am still getting the same issue.

Comment: @Flashpacker: Did you check the demo?

Comment: ok sure, I will play around with it, so I can never use true? Has to be false?

Comment: @Flashpacker: Yeah, that's the recommended way to do it. Have a look at the official documentation for [`strpos()`](http://php.net/strpos).

Answer (score -1):

check this

```
 $test = 'ORDER BY `views`';
   if (strpos($test,'views') !== false) {
        echo 'true';
    } else {
        echo 'false';
    }
```

also use

You can use these string functions,

[strstr](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) — Find the first occurrence of a string

[stristr](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stristr.php) — Case-insensitive strstr()

[strrchr](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strrchr.php) — Find the last occurrence of a character in a string

[strpos](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) — Find the position of the first occurrence of a substring in a string

[strpbrk](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpbrk.php) — Search a string for any of a set of characters

If that doesn't help then you should use `preg` regular expression

[preg_match](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) — Perform a regular expression match

Comment: How is this different from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19248048/1438393) answer (except the curly braces)?

Comment: @AmalMurali put this answer 30 minutes before :) Why do You duplicate answer?

Comment: @Adam AND AmalMurali check now